# QGIS road style appears blocky, I want it to appear continuous. Is there a style merge function or something similar?

Tags: qgis, style

If you look closely and see the main roads, they break down into blocks [][][][].

I was wondering in QGIS how can I have them appear continuous and not blocked up as shown below. This is one file and not multiple ones.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the style settings for the layer. It *looks like* your roads layer is made up of many short line segments, but without seeing your style settings it's not possible to be sure.

Comment: Try setting the 'cap style' on both the white and grey layers to 'flat'